# Cannot open Fyrox editor, fails to compile

Tags: ubuntu

While trying to open Fyrox editor for the first time, it gives me this error:

```
'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Custom("\"No such file or directory\"")', /home/cody/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/fyroxed_base-0.17.0/src/lib.rs:498:56
```

I am not sure based on this output what file or directory it is trying to get to.

I also noticed at the top of the output is says:

```
[ERROR]: Failed to load settings, fallback to default. Reason: Io(Os { code: 2, kind: NotFound, message: "No such file or directory" })
Insufficient atlas size!
```

However, the code seemed to continue to compile just fine after this.

I tried deleting the old files and retrying with the Latest version, but I got the same error.

I am using Ubuntu 22.10

Comment: Stack Overflow is about _programming_ issues, unless you're developing Fyrox, your question is likely off-topic. Instead, you should contact the developers of Fyrox, or its community of users, and ask them for help.